# Delayed Job adding special characters to rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, character-encoding, delayed-job

I queue a delayed job task that saves an objects json representation to s3. One of the attributes for the object is copyright_info, which includes a copyright symbol. The copyright symbol appears fine in the database and if I 'puts object.copyright_info' in the controller, but when I 'puts object.copyright_info' in the delayed job file it has added special characters.

```
Controller

def create_json
  puts @object.copyright_info #copy right symbol appears correctly - "Copyright ©"
  Delayed::Job.enqueue SaveS3Json.new(@object)
end
```

Save json file:

```
class SaveS3Json < Struct.new(:object)
  # encoding: utf-8

  def perform
    puts object.copyright_info #outputs "Copyright Â©"
    # calls object.to_json and writes json file to s3
 end
```

I'm running on Heroku with ruby-1.9.2-p32 and Postgresql. When I do this same task locally, special characters do not seem to be added.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by simply passing the object ID rather than the full object to the Struct.new() class. Once I had the ID in the SaveS3Json class, I simply did a normal Active Record .find(id) and the object was retrieved without any special characters added.

Thanks!